# How can i verify if the object has a value before displaying image?

Tags: php, html, image, object, foreach

I need to be able to verify that the object has a value so then if it does not have a value then no image will display:

```
<?php
     for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { ?>
        <td><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.6.1/img/item/<?php echo $game->stats->{'item' .$i}; ?>.png"></img></td>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($game)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an if statement that checks if the value is empty or not.

```
echo (!empty($games->stats->value) ? "print images" : "something else");
```

something like that.

Comment: when i use the i ALWAYS get a something else returned even if an image should exist?

Comment: you should know what data type you are expecting to return,
i assume you are expecting a string, you can add an is_string() to your statement. if its not then you can go print other image,

Answer (score 0):

We have a special function in PHP for all empty or NIL checks.
Just make an if and check:

```
if (!empty($myobj->Obj)) //Not empty
```

Comment: !empty always returns nothing for me

Comment: Can we see what contain this object? Maybe key? You can check hard by key.